# How to make a div glow with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, colors, glow

I wonder how to make a div glow in a specific color when the page has loaded.

```
<div id="glow" class="logo registrer"><a href="http://henricson.net/registrer.php" class="understrek">Registrer deg</a></div>
```

This is the div i want to glow.
Thank you :)

Comment: What do you mean by *glow*? Can you post the code you tried in your attempts at solving this?

Comment: Look at [JQuery Effects](http://jqueryui.com/effect/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS3 can do that:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue;
box-shadow:0 0 20px blue;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw5Ys/) that shows that it does, in fact, it works fine with me, check it out to see :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you mean to glow? If to simply change colour then you can do something like the below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#glow').animate({backgroundColor:'green'});
});
```

You could then add some `box-shadow` to add a glow effect.

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(0, 150, 0, 0.3);
```

Please see this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXY5F/1/) of an animating background colour and shadow added.

**EDIT**

Sorry I forgot to mention you'll need to include the [color animation plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) to be able to do this.

Also here is another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXY5F/2/) that runs after half a second and then removes the glow.... obviously this would need alot of tweaking to make it look nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="notificationmain">
  <div class="sub"><blockquote id="notification" class="alert alert-success" glowing="0">User Has been created</blockquote></div>  

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            setTimeout(function () { $('.sub blockquote').glow('#FFFFDD', 800); }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

You need to reference

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.glow.js"></script>
```